# Condition LIKE with strtotime in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, strtotime

Is it possible to create a condition for it to search values by day, month and year when the date was added with `strtotime` in the database?

The insert is done this way in the DB:

```
$data['date_added'] = strtotime(date('D, d-M-Y'));
```

The code I'm trying to make work:

```
$total = $this->db
        ->select_sum('amount','total')
        ->like('date_added', strtotime(date('01-02-2019')))
        ->get('payment')
        ->row_array();
        echo $total['total'];
```

If I enter the full date `strtotime(date('01-02-2019'))` it returns the results, but I need to search by month and year `strtotime(date('02-2019'))` or `strtotime(date('2019'))`.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the timestamp and compare it to your month-year string. Not tested but something like this:

`->where('FROM_UNIXTIME(date_added, "%m-%Y") = "02-2019"', NULL, FALSE)`

And for year:

`->where('FROM_UNIXTIME(date_added, "%Y") = "2019"', NULL, FALSE)`